# GetDirectories Query

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem item;
        string folderLocation = @"\\serv5007i\TeamCityDeploy\Trunk Production Build\Current\bin\Runtime";
        int startSize = folderLocation.Length+1;

        ListItem item2;
        string appConfig = "AppConfig";

        ListItem OnlineRuntimesToDeploy;
        string onlineServices = "Online Services";

        string[] fileNames = Directory.GetDirectories(folderLocation).Where(x => !x.Contains("anagedC")).Take(13).ToArray();
        foreach (string fileName in fileNames)

       {

            item = new ListItem();
            item2 = new ListItem();
            OnlineRuntimesToDeploy = new ListItem();
            item.Value = fileName.Substring(startSize);
            item2.Value = item2.Text = "Add AppConfig for " + fileName.Substring(startSize);
            OnlineRuntimesToDeploy.Value = "";
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);
            CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(item2);
            CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(OnlineRuntimesToDeploy);

        }
```

Hi, 
I am trying to figure this out. What I have is two columns outputting the names of the folders in my directory(13 of the folders). I am wondering , can I do another GetDirectories, to take just 3 more. For example, folders in position 14-16?

For example: I have 
1
2
..
13

Now I want a third column to just contain
14
15
16

If that makes sense

Comment: "If that makes sense". No, sorry, it doesn't. What are all these numbers 1, 2, 13 etc?

Comment: They're just examples. So my main directory is:
Folder 1 
Folder 2
Folder 3
Folder 4
Folder 5
Folder 6
Folder 7
Folder 8
Folder 9
Folder 10
Folder 11
Folder 12
Folder 13
Folder 14
Folder 15
Folder 16
My first column contains Folder 1 to Folder 13.
I want my third column to contain Folder 14, Folder 15 and Folder 16.

Comment: yeah I guess you have to make another call to GetDirectories, as Elmer's answer suggests. If you actually have more than 16 though, you'll have to add another parameter to only take exactly 3 records. Or, alternatively, you make one call to GetDirectories and retrieve every folder. Then loop through them. Keep a count of the folder number (incremented once per loop), and when you get to 14, start a new column

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner so this is where I'm at and obviously its working. I'm calling another GetDirectories then running it through a foreach loop? This is all quite new to me so appreciate your patience
http://imgur.com/a/CfOY2

Comment: no..just call it once, and include _all_ the files (i.e. don't use Take or Skip at all). And then yes, run it through a foreach loop. Or a for loop - this will keep the count for you automatically.

Comment: Ok, so I call it and it outputs all folders. Do I use the .Take or .Skip elsewhere?

Comment: not unless you want to. Just loop through them, keep count of where you're up to (in a variable - if you use a for loop it does this by default). When you get to 14, create a new column in whatever your output format is and start adding them to that instead. (It's not clear from the code how you are creating different columns, but you seem to have some idea how that will work already).

Comment: Thanks for your help, still struggling with it. I gotta spend some more time trying to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a ordered list,

```
Directory.GetDirectories(folderLocation).Where(x => !x.Contains("anagedC")).Skip(13).ToArray();
```

This should work.

Comment: Can I place this under the previous Directory.GetDirectories line with string[] OnlineRuntimesToDeploy? I get errors for that

Comment: looking at the image you've posted you declare `OnlineRuntimesToDeploy` as `ListItem`...and use it again as `string[] OnlineRuntimesToDeploy` remove the  `ListItem OnlineRuntimesToDeploy` line and everything should work (if you need another variable of `ListItem`, just create with another name)